# After seeding data in EFCore 3.1.1 code first, is it possible to set identity value to last id inserted + 1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, code-first

So, i am seeding some Identity Server Users with Id's 1,2,3 and 4 respectively. After trying to insert a new user after running the application, i have to 'try' to insert 4 times, before the ID is set at 5 and i can start inserting without errors.

I have tried searching for an answer, but have came up short. The question - is this doable trough Code-First approach, by using the ModelBuilder or query to database after seeding is done?

Also, i am using PostgreSQL database with code-first approach in Asp Net Core application.

EDIT: Also, here is all the ID column constraints, which show that it is a identity column.

[image]

Comment: Why do you care what the IDs are anyway? Let the DB create the ID. For example, if it's PostgreSQL, use identity (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/).

Comment: @DavidG Because you can't seed data without ID's. I.E. **The seed entity for entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'Id'. Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.** Gets thrown

Comment: Yes, that's because you are not using an identity column. Like I said, go read the link and look up how to use them with EF.

Comment: So yes, you can seed data without specifying the ID, I do it all the time.

Comment: @DavidG Every Id value has the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute added, so i'm pretty sure that adding Identity doesn't change data seeding functionality, it still needs an ID value.

Comment: "Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data." sounds like good advice. What happens if you use negative numbers for your seed ID values?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I and coworkers disliked the idea of  putting negative values on database entries, so we found another way to fix the issue in below answer i gave. Setting negative values should be okay, but what if you have validity checks in the system where Id must be bigger than 0? Seems like too much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I found a more correct fix than setting negative values on database entries.

```
// Set starting value to start after seeded data count. Must be done
// to any entity, that can be added to from application logic.
builder.Entity<SomeTable>()
    .Property(b => b.YourIdProperty)
    .HasIdentityOptions(startValue: seededDataCount + 1);
```

This is for postgreSQL, but should work really similiarly for other implementations.